# Scenario Analysis

Tags: ms-project

I am fairly new to MS project, challenge is that the project is already delayed, and I need to test, if adding more tasks, in which we are getting external consultants will speed up the development process and what the impact would be on cost and schedule. I need to meet the schedule.
Is there a way this can be tested in MS project?

Any help or starting point would be helpful.

Comment: Did you mean adding more staff or adding more tasks?

Comment: Yes, I need to experiment what results some changes to staff will do, plus another scenario is to add more tasks and some consultants onboadrd to speed up the work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine how adding tasks would help speed up a schedule. Typically, removing work would be considered to help cure an unfavorable schedule variance.

Adding staff is a mix bag. It depends on the resource elasticity of the work you are performing, the environment in which the work is being done, the ramp-up time for the new staff, and about 100 other variables. Many here will cite the Mythical Man Month and tell you it is impossible. That's not necessarily true. Depends is the right answer.

You can make MSProject read anything. It won't give you answers except what you load in there. You need to re-estimate the planning values of the tasks remaining considering the extra staff and determine how risky the values are.

If you are able to evaluate your new estimates using Monte Carlo simulation, you may determine the likelihood your staffing intervention will return favorable results. There is a lot to simulating properly so you'll need to find an expert to help you with that. There's too much with it to answer properly here.

Comment: I do understand what you are saying, what I am thinking is that since i need to create and test scenarios, would defining additional baselines help? And with that I might be able to see the results on EV view and see the differences?!